# How to resize the font size in sidebar navigation menu for Magento 2.3.4 (Luma theme)

Tags: css, magento2.3.0, navigation, sidebar, resize

I am doing a migration from 1.9.3 to magento 2.3.4 and i somehow managed to move the top navigation menu to the sidebar with a mod that was posted on this site for magento 2.3.4 However each menu line spills over to two lines in my navigation sidebar.

Should i change the font size or may be i can change the width of the side bar

How can i do this ?? Please help
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Decrease line-height of navigation li tag to either 1 or 1.5. Css will be

```
line-height: 1.5 !important;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but where do i change this ??  Appreciate the directory link

Comment: Send me website link or you need to check navigation class name and write css for it.